# PHP numerical methods

Tags: php, numerical-methods

I have a non-linear function, and I need to find a root for it. Does anyone knows if there's a library for PHP that implements numerical methods?

(I can write the method, but I'd like to know if out there is a library that does the job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) has [Math_Numerical_RootFinding](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Numerical_RootFinding/docs/latest/li_Math_Numerical_RootFinding.html).